# New well pump, and foot valve and suction line

Tags: valve, pump, well, pressure, shallow

Ok to explain alittle, our well pump went out... I replaced pump... then the foot valve clogged and sucked the suction line flat causing it to fall off... and suck air... I then replaced foot valve and entire suction line.... primed pump... and it won't build pressure... also changed switch to be sure it was getting adequate power supply to the pump... still nothing.... im at a lose.. and ideas will be helpful

Comment: How long was it sucking air? That can kill even a brand new pump. A rebuild kit should bring it back from the dead, since the motor is presumably fine.

Comment: ...And this is why a pressure switch that shuts off when low pressure is experienced is a normal thing.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the foot valve is actually holding water. Even a small piece of dirt can make it leak and lose the prime. If you are sure that the foot valve is working and the pump housing is full of water, then you probably burnt the seals by running it dry. Time for a rebuild.